# displaying sentence using string chunks

Tags: c#, .net, xml

here is a program i made to display all the possible strings containing "who" & "your" within an xml file. The xml file contains few sentences  like:
how are you,what is your name,what is your school name. The program which i code is displaying the sentences if both "who" and "you" comes one after one. How can i break a string into chunks and then pass them to check through xml.
The code whice i tried is :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("dic.xml");
string findString = "what your";
var results = doc.Descendants("s")
                 .Where(d => d.Value.Contains(findString.ToLower()))
                 .Select(d => d.Value);

foreach (string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please be more specific, explaining in detail what the input looks like (including a _small_-but-complete example), how the algorithm you are trying to implement would process the input, and what the output of the implementation would look like. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: i simply want to display all the sentences which posses both of these words but as i am passing them as a single string, i want to split this string into chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check if each result contains "who" and "your". Your original code was looking for the string "who your" not the two strings "who" and "your".  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link for information on `string.Contains(string)`

**Code**

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("dic.xml");

var results = doc.Descendants("s").Where(d => d.Value.Contains("your") || d.Value.Contains("who")).Select(d => d.Value);

foreach (string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Edit: Misread your original code and put the filtering in the wrong spot

Comment: No problem, I just edited the question because I misunderstood your code. The edited version should work better

Comment: @TabiaRashid It sounded like in your original statement that you wanted sentences that contain both words and in a specific order?
Won't this only return sentences that have either word? And even if it was changed to and, it still wouldn't respect the order.... Or did i misunderstand your goals?

Comment: no i just want the sentences which contains the specific words i provided